# Xavier initialisation of weights for 3D convolutions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, tensorflow

I am using 3D convolutions in tensorflow. I want to initialise the weights using Xavier initialisation.
Tensorflow has an implementation of [Xavier initialisation for 2D convolutions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer), from this reference and the original [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) I figured the initialisation (for uniform distribution $[-x, x]$) should be something like:
$$x = \sqrt{\frac{6}{height \times width \times depth \times (\#channels_{in} + \#channels_{out})}}$$,
where $height, width, depth$ are the dimensions of the convolution's patch (3 dimensional) and $\#channels_{in}, \#channels_{out}$ are the number of channels that go in and out of the convolution layer.
Where this hopefully corresponds to:
$$ x = \sqrt{\frac{6}{\#weightsOfLayer}}
$$
Can someone please verify if my reasoning is correct, that is, does the denominator correspond the number of weights in the layer, and should I be calculating the number of weights in the layer in the first place?